# jffs2dump errors upon converting to little-endian

Tags: filesystems, embedded, embedded-linux, endianness, jffs2

dmesg :

```
jffs2_scan_eraseblock(): Magic bitmask 0x1985 not found at 0x00c50000: 0x1eb6 instead
```

jffs2dump:

```
Converting image to little endian...
Wrong bitmask  at  0x00c50000, 0x1eb6
Wrong bitmask  at  0x00c50004, 0x0000
Wrong bitmask  at  0x00c50008, 0x0000
Wrong bitmask  at  0x00c5000c, 0x0000
Wrong bitmask  at  0x00c50010, 0x0000
```

What is causing this? how can i fix that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The image that you are dumping is not a valid JFFS2.
It must have at least one erase block, it start with 0x8519 (0x1985 little endian).

Try with cat /proc/partition to see your partition table